# Delay in starting the next stage in Spark job

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

While looking into the stage details for a spark job which takes very long time than usual; it is observed that the '*stage n*' does not start even after all the '*stages from 0 to n-1*' have been completed.

The enclosed details are from the spark details of a job/build -> stage progress.

[image]

I am unable to get the reason behind this lag where the stage-8 starts after a long delay (12.48 AM vs 1.25 AM).  As you can see; all the stages above 8 get completed in seconds or minutes and the delay of 37 minutes between the highlighted stages is something puzzles me.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: how big are your datasets and how many files does it have?

Comment: The stages 1-7 handle the dataset with 5.2 GB size approx with 1884 files.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that that lag between both stages is IO happening. I would recommend you partition your datasets so that each file has 128MB each. Opening, writing and closing 1884 files takes time, and with 5.2GB of size you could do this with around 40 files.

```
df.repartition(40)
```

should help.